# Could not find an overload for "+" that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift

Look at this code:

```
var timepenalty = UInt8(0)   
var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

// Find the difference between current time and start time
var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

let adjustedTime = UInt8(timepenalty + elapsedTime)

error-
"Could not find an overload for "+" that accepts the requested arguments.
"
```

This is for a game that adds time to the stopwatch-style timer, every time the player makes a mistake. The code works when I just use an integer instead of the elapsedTime variable as so:

```
let adjustedTime = UInt8(elapsedTime + 5)
```

but replacing 5 with a variable gives an error.

Here's the full code for the `updateTime` function:

```
func updateTime() {


        var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

        // Find the difference between current time and start time
        var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

        let adjustedTime = UInt8(timepenalty + elapsedTime)
        // calculate the minutes in elapsed time
        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
        elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        // calculate the seconds in elapsed time


        seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
        elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
//        seconds += timepenalty

        // find out the fraction of millisends to be displayed
        let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

        //            if seconds > 20 {
        //                exceedMsgLabel.text = "超过20秒了"
        //            }

        // add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants


        let startMinutes  = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
        let startSeconds  = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)
        let startFraction = fraction > 9 ? String(fraction):"0" + String(fraction)

        displayTimeLabel.text = "\(startMinutes):\(startSeconds):\(startFraction)"
        var penalty = String(timepenalty)
        penaltylabel.text = "+ " + penalty


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
let adjustedTime = UInt8(timepenalty + elapsedTime)
```

is attempting to add a `UInt8` (time penalty) and an `NSTimeInterval` (double, elapsedTime) which fails as there is no implicit type conversion in Swift.  Change it to:

```
let adjustedTime = timepenalty + UInt8(elapsedTime)
```

Which converts the `NSTimeInterval` to a UInt8 before the addition.

Comment: Note that it'd probably be simpler to convert (leave actually) most of this math to Double rather than downsizing it to Uint8 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

@David's code is good, but I'd strongly recommend that you make `adjustedTime` be an `NSTimeInterval`. It is a time interval, and that's what the type is for. Then all your casting issues go away.

The `UInt8` type is reserved for cases where you explicitly need an 8-bit bit-pattern (like for networking protocols or binary file formats). It isn't intended for "small numbers." Moving between signed and unsigned numbers and different sized-numbers are common sources of bugs, and is intentionally made cumbersome.

If you do need to force a `Double` to be a whole number, just use `Int` rather than `UInt8` in most cases. In most of these cases it looks like you really mean `floor()` rather than `Int()` anyway. You're just normalizing to an whole number.

That said, a more typical way to do your formatting is:

```
import Foundation

let totalSeconds: NSTimeInterval = 100.51

let frac = Int((totalSeconds - floor(totalSeconds)) * 100)
let seconds = Int(totalSeconds % 60)
let minutes = Int((totalSeconds / 60) % 60)

let result = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds, frac)
```

Comment: Thanks, next I need to find out how to make adjustedTime a NSTimeInterval .  This is a good tip, thanks again.

Comment: Michael, you seem to be storing times as `NSTimeInterval` (eg., `startTime`)  What you should really be doing is storing them as `NSDate` and then when you need to know the delta between two, calculate an NSTimeInterval using `now.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)`  That way things keep their inherent types as long as possible.

Comment: @Rob agreed, which was the point of my comment on my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`UInt8` and `NSTimeInterval` are two different types. You need to make each operand the same type. (Or you could use operator overloading.)

Comment: what type is NSTimeInterval?  how to use operator overloading? thanks